# Equivalent in scala of matrix crossprod in R

Tags: scala

I can make a crossproduct as a cartersian one with a double loop :

```
 for(i<-Array(...);j<-Array(...)) yield(ij)
```

But with this way of proceding i obtain doublon "ij" & "ji".
How can i avoid this behaviour in scala ?
I would like to have the same behaviour that the crossprod function in R for two matrix.

```
 > m1
       [,1] [,2]
 [1,]    1    3
 [2,]    2    4

 > m2
        [,1] [,2]
 [1,]    5    7
 [2,]    6    8

 > crossprod(m1,m2)
       [,1] [,2]
 [1,]   17   23
 [2,]   39   53
```

I want to obtain the same result from 2 Array[Array[Double]] in scala but i suppose that i can't use the double for loop as present at beginning due to doublon we obtain from it.

The exemple use size 2 squared matrix but i will be to apply in n*m matrix.

Comment: *i obtain doublon "ij" & "ji"* Can you elaborate on what you mean by that?

Comment: Please can you provide example input and output? Your code won't compile (since `ij` does not exist). Also, is this a cartesian (i.e. both arrays are the same) or a cross product of two different arrays?

Comment: ... in Scala, preferably. I've done a quick google for R's crossprod and it's not obvious to me what you want. Also, your examples suggest you're using   2-d matrices (so in Scala, Arrays of Arrays) so your scala fragment is misleading, at best. It won't be a simple iteration of the top level array. And your Scala code is still incorrect. What do you mean by `yield (Ij)`? A tuple? a product?

Comment: I want to obtain the crossprod(m1,m2) matrix in R from an Array[Array[Double]] in scala

Comment: OK. PLEASE fix your scala. Also "The exemple use 2d matrix but i will be to apply in n\*m matrix." An n\*m matrix is a 2d matrix, so that addition is just confusing, Can you clarify?

Comment: I don't know which scala code to show it was supposed to be an beginning of hint to solve my problem.
My problem is for 2d matrix of various size in column and row

Comment: So if  I understand correctly it's m1 transposed multipled by m2?

Comment: Yes, you're right it would solve my problem. Thank you

Comment: (My last comment) so there's already a `.transpose` method defined for Arrays (and other sequences). I assume you already have or can do a matrix multiply

Comment: OK, I lied:) here's a page with all you need (`transpose` - although as I said, that's standard) and matrix-multiply https://medium.com/@eob/how-you-might-create-a-scala-matrix-library-in-a-functional-programming-style-760f8bf6ee6#.z41hins5z